# How to infer a python class generic based on a method input?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

I want to write a pipeline in python like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")
V = TypeVar("V")


class Pipeline(Generic[T, U]):
    def pipe(self, _cb: Callable[[U], V]) -> "Pipeline[T, V]":
        ...


def int_to_str(x: int) -> str:
    return str(x)


a = Pipeline()
a = a.pipe(int_to_str)
     # the inferred type is Pipeline[Unknown, str]
     # I would like it to be Pipeline[int, str]
```

is there anyway that python can understand that because the first function passed is a function that takes int as an inout, then the pipeline first generic type should be an int?

I tried to play with @overload etc. but I can't make it work.

Comment: You can't, it goes again static type checking goals. You need to **check** that method calls are correct ("is this call correct?"). You are not allowed to say "this method call is indeed correct, infer the rest" - it's not like "assume no UB" compiler rule in C and C++.